# Rails - custom scaffold_generator with models outside of namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I want to create a custom scaffold_generator with a namespace like this

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Admin::Posts --assets=false
```

therefore i put the controller.rb into

```
lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb
```

and it works fine... but every time it asks for a model it also searches for the model in the ADMIN:: namespace..

Is there a way to scaffold the controller but use the models from outside the namespace like

```
Posts.all
```

not

```
Admin::Posts.all
```

In the controller.rb file I saw that the Model Name is generated with

```
<%= orm_class.all(class_name) %>
```

Comment: Rails questions should not be tagged as Ruby (according to the Ruby tag wiki). Please remove the Ruby tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use "nifty-generators" or "rails-admin-scaffold" (https://github.com/dhampik/rails-admin-scaffold).